# Use Python value inside Javascript variable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use a value from python inside javascript that's executed in that python script.
I've tried with formatting, searched everywhere on SO, but no luck. Hopefully, someone will be willing to help me.

Basically what I'm trying to do is replace words on web page with links around those words (for example "google" into "<a href="http://google.com""). These words and links come from csv, which is read via python and then used as vars inside javascript executor (var search = "variable from csv"). And that's where I'm stucked, as I cannot get those python variables to get used inside javascript "var". Hope I'm making sense.

Here's the code:

```
                  js = """var search = "google" # this works
                          var search = "{}";.format(mystring) # but this doesn't
                          var replacement = "{}";.format(mylink)
                          var replacementTag = '"+replacement+"' target='_blank'>"+search+"</a>";
                          document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacementTag);
                       """

                  driver.execute_script(js)
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need the `.format` call *after* the closing `"""`

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried it and it doesn't work. Any other ideas perhaps?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and explain how it "doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm trying to replace links in DOM with my own, based on searched words. For this, I'd like to send variables from python to javascript (var = "replaced link"), but cannot send it no matter what I do. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I mean, please edit your question to show your attempt which has the `.format` after the string, so I (and others!) can see what is wrong with it. Your original code, which has `.format` inside the string literal, is not much help with that. And show us what the actual produced javascript code produced is, if that's not correct (you can always `print(js)` to see!)

Comment: Sorry, now I edited my question. I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Your edit has exactly the same problem as I pointed to - your uses of `.format` are *inside* the string literal, so of course they "don't work", your string of Javascript literally includes `var search = "{}";.format(mystring)` (which is not even valid Javascript code). What I suggested, which you appear not to have tried even though you said you did, was to change it to `js = """your JS string including {} placeholders""".format(mystring)`. (Although note your `.format` will need one argument for each `{}` in the string.

Comment: I did try as you suggested, but nothing happended. So I came to conclusion that it cannot be done directly from python to js, but I'd need to use something like json.dumps or similar. Any thoughts on this maybe? Btw, thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: Yes it should be able to be done. But I can only help if I see your "latest" failing code, with my suggestion - otherwise I can't possibly guess what you've done wrong. Imagine you're answering a question and you see that the answer is, say, to change a variable from 0 to 1 (or whatever) - and in response to you saying that, the questioner says "tried that, it didn't work" with no further detail. You'd find it impossible to know what's gone wrong, right - especially if you know that what you suggested should work. Well that's the position you've put me in here.

Comment: I understand, my bad, sorry. Here's what I tried with json: first I did this in python: mystring = json.dumps(string) and then this in js: var search = JSON.parse(mystring); but nothing happened. Is this the right way to go and what do I need to change to work? Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not - because it depends on what `my_string` is and you haven't fixed that. In my very first comment I told you how I thought you should fix it, and all I've had since is "that didn't work", without you ever showing me the updated code. Despite repeated requests, you have still not edited your question to include that, or otherwise showed me code that uses the format method correctly - so I have no idea what you're doing wrong. I'm trying not to sound rude but this is getting pretty frustrating and I don't feel inclined to respond again if you still refuse to help me help you.

Comment: To be clear as to what I'm looking for, this was an earlier comment: What I suggested, which you appear not to have tried even though you said you did, was to change it to js = """your JS string including {} placeholders""".format(mystring). (Although note your .format will need one argument for each {} in the string.)